# Update InfoPath form field value in SharePoint Online document library?

Tags: infopath, filter, infopath-rules, infopath-data-connections, update

I have saved InfoPath Form in a Form Library & also saved field values in separate columns, now I have retrieved one record in InfoPath Form 2013.
I'm trying  to update **Status** columns value from **New**  to **old** but unable to update that value.

Instead of updating it adds new record in Form Library.

I have tried to filter the record on button click, but not found any filter on button click.

My InfoPath Form Fields are-

```
Name :   <People Picker> Control
Status:  <textbox>
```

Comment: Maybe because of your filename? Be sure your filename is not changing for each submit.

Answer (score 0):

There are two button in Ribbon of InfoPath Form `Save`and `Submit`.

`Submit` button will always create a new list item in the document library whereas `Save` button will update the existing form.

So, for the first time submission you should use `Submit` button. Later, if any update is required in the existing form, click on `Save` button instead of `Submit` otherwise a new list item will be created.

Comment: i have to use custom button in Infopath form. so how can i use save button in My infopath form

Comment: I'm having same problem actually. Next thing I would try is Managed Code in InfoPath to save/update the form. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using buttons as `Submit` and `Save`, you should modify your Submit Data Connection.

First create a field that will handle the File name of your form. Name this `FileName`. Create a action rule either on form load or `Submit` button. Take note that put in the Condition of the rule that if the field is blank then produce a file name value (It can be any format that you want). This condition will eliminate the creation of a new file name value after submission.

Now go to your Submit Data Connection, put in the `FileName` field under File Name and check the "Allow overwrite if file exists".

Put a rule in `Submit` and `Save` button with your Submit Data Connection. The idea is that when creating new form, the FileName is still blank and still not saved. After submission, the FileName will not produce a new one but use the saved value. When `Save` button is pressed, it will overwrite the existing form

Comment: i don't want to "Allow overwrite if file exists", i just want to update the particular field in Form Library, because there is workflow for form library

Comment: Just to clarify, you are updating status field using workflow? Or the workflow is triggered by that field?

Regarding my answer, the overwrite will serve as "saving your updates" instead of the submit/save creating a new form. You will overwrite the old form with your new form having the updated value on the particular field